# Can not delete Document Set "The file is currently checked out or locked for editing by another user."

Tags: 2013, error, document-set, delete

I have a Doc Set I can not delete.  I've tried to delete it via Windows Explorer (in case that would help) and via the Content and Structure menu, but to no avail.

As you see in the pictures below, Sharepoint thinks there are checked out or locked documents.  The folders are actually empty.  There were 7 folders within the Doc Set, I have deleted 4 of them, three remain.

Any ideas as to what could be causing the error message?

[image: pic of doc set error message]

[image: pic of sub-folder error message]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah...I finally figured it out, having just posted the question...

There were invisible files inside the sub-folders, I've no idea why they were invisible.

I checked the Site Collection Recycle Bin, in case a file had been deleted, but the 30 days had not yet passed - since files are only deleted after 30 days I believe.

Then I found the answer:  `Manage files which have no checked in version`.  There were load of these files, so I took ownership of them.  Then Sharepoint allowed me to delete the document set (and all sub-folders contained within it AND all files contained within the sub-folders).

[image]

[image]